# jQuery key press event not working with alert

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code which will not allow user to enter anything except a-z A-Z 0-9 when length is 0. I want to alert user that he is not allowed to enter special characters. The problem is when I hit space, the alert appears and disappears within a fraction of a second. What is wrong with my code?

```
    $('#value').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if($('#value').val().length == 0){
            if (e.which == 32){//space bar
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (e.which < 48 || 
                    (e.which > 57 && e.which < 65) || 
                    (e.which > 90 && e.which < 97) ||
                    e.which > 122) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                        alert("Not allowed");
            }
        }
    });   

    <input type="text" id="value" />
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fwcfq/39/)

Comment: It looks like some code got lost during the cut+paste. I'm assuming `$('#DivisionName')` should actually be `$('#value')`. Also, how are you displaying the alert?

Comment: Don't see any code for an alert?

Comment: Please find my edited post. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: The code you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fwcfq/46/

Comment: Alert is coming but disappears before I could read what is written in it

Comment: hitting space,on keyup selects ok button of that alert.because of that alert vanishes..

Comment: Then how do I notify user that he is not allowed to use such characters?

Answer (score 0):

Few advices:

1. use on method instead of bind method
2. when you are in the method callback you can refer to the element with "this" keyword

besides the advices here is the code and fiddle.

```
$('#value').on('keypress', function(e) {
            if($(this).val().length == 0){
                if (e.which == 32){//space bar
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("just some text");
                }
                var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
if (!valid) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwcfq/45/

Comment: still the same. Alert is coming but disappears before I could read what is written in it

Comment: @AnushaHoney - Are you sure you're not pressing [ SPACE ] *twice*? Pressing space once would show the alert dialog box, then pressing space again would probably close the dialog.

Comment: I very much sure that I am not pressing it twice.

Comment: @AnushaHoney - Well, the code that pm.calabrese posted works fine for me in Firefox. So I don't think it's a problem with the JavaScript. What browser are you using?

Comment: Then I think the problem is not in the code you provide us, are you binding other events to this element? Because if so... then i'll suggest you to check if they "collide" in some way giving a bad effect...

Comment: @AnushaHoney I've tested my jsFiddle and works correct in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to the question and answer, you may want to think about a different way of displaying an alert to the user. You can use jQuery to show/hide an element on the page that alerts the user. For example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="value" />
<p id="alert" style="display:none">Not allowed!</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#value').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    var showAlert = false;
    if ($('#value').val().length == 0) {
        if (e.which == 32) { //space bar
            e.preventDefault();
            showAlert = true;
        }
        var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)
                    || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90)
                    || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
        if (!valid) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showAlert = true;
        }
    }
    if (showAlert) {
        $('#alert').show();
    } else {
        $('#alert').hide();
    }
});
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fwcfq/47/

Comment: I want to alert user. Not displaying in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code and it's ok

```
$('#value').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32){//space bar
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
    if (!valid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Not allowed");
    }
});
```

I deleted this test

```
if($('#value').val().length == 0)
```